# Layered/Tiered Architecture - Segregation of code

Tags: java, oop, spring-mvc, design-patterns, architecture

From last few months I have been working on an enterprise application with `spring-mvc`. I have heard about 3-layer architecture with these layers/tiers - **UI, Business Logic** and **DAO.** This architecture is known to me. But while working on some `spring-mvc` enterprise projects I have found some layers like this (based on the code flow) -

```
 Controller  
    |
    v  
 Service  
    |  
    v
 Manager  
    |  
    v
   Dao
```

I found the above layerd structure a bit confusing compared with 3-layer architecture. Because I have found some business logic written in both **service** and **manager** layer. The mixing up might be caused by lack of care or there wouldn't be other options rather doing this. But like 3-layer architecture there may be some reason behind each layer. Can someone explain why these layer for?

Probably this is not a good question based on `stackoverflow`'s specification. But this would be helpful enough as as a suggestions/tips to follow for new developer like me.
Thanks.

Comment: [ports and adapters](http://alistair.cockburn.us/Hexagonal+architecture) are a better architectural alternative to the linear approach suggested on your diagram and to the 3-tier approach you mention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented a design very similar to the one you describe. My reasoning behind it was the "Manager" layer would help abstract any specific data access code away from the service layer.

So a service that looked like this (pseudo-code):

```
function getCustomer(id) {
    sql = "select * from customer where id = @id";
    return db->execute(sql, id);
}
```

ended up looking like this:

```
function getCustomer(id) {
   return dbo->getCustomerById(id);
}
```

This extra layer did a few things for my project. It centralized all data access, allowing me to use the manager classes in other projects. It also gave me the option (heaven forbid) to more easily switch between different data storage strategies (structured sql -> nosql) without having to change any of my service layer code.

Comment: and what is in your DAO when "Manager" contains SQL statement?

Comment: its not a perfect example, but my dao would be the repositories, manager would orchestrate the repositories and build my aggregates.

Comment: @Zach Spencer so we can say we can use **manager** class here for controlling/managing data access and **service** for business logic?

Comment: @Razib Sure, in this example that was the intent.

Answer (score 0):

That is an MVC (Model-View-Controller) Architecture rather then the older (but still widely used) Data - Business Logic -- UI  model.  They are simply different architectural models and while they can and are compared and contrasted they most definitely do not map to each other one for one.  If you find yourself working on a project that utilizes MVC I highly recommend that you find a book on MVC (or even specifically on Spring-MVC) and do some studying.